# Issues while referring 'this' when calling 'new' in js

Tags: javascript

I am facing issues while trying to refer this/that inside a 'new' call.

I am creating  an object using new operator. Code structure is like this(I am dummying here to make it js specific)

```
var that = this
this.myObj = new AnotherClass({
  sources: [dummyarg],
  operation: (x,y) => {
    that.dummyMemberVariable.dummyMethod(that.dummyData)
  }
});
```

AnotherClass is from a library, dummyMemberVariable and dummyData are defined in the class enclosing this code.

Issue is 'that' is undefined.

How to tackle it?

Edit: Overall structure of the code is as follows

> Outer class(OC) has method A. A calls another method B which too is defined in OC.
>   The original code I posted is in B. So A and B are at same level in OC.

I posted actual code on another post but that become too much specific to the library I am using. But if that helps, here it is:

[Unable to access correct 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164985/unable-to-access-correct-this)

Comment: Sounds like the calling context of the outer block is wrong. Need more code to figure out how to fix it

Comment: Does replacing `that.dummyMemberVariable.dummyMethod(that.dummyData)` with `this.dummyMemberVariable.dummyMethod(this.dummyData)` work?

Comment: @Eisenheim, that approach also didn't work.

Comment: Need to see more code

Comment: `Issue is 'that' is undefined.` but what is `this` when you assign it to `that` - that is this questions unknown - `I am dummying here` - oh, right, so the code you presented in the question isn't even real code - don't think you'll get a real or useful answer in that case - if you're going to post `dummy` code, post `dummy` code that at least *demonstrates* your issue

Comment: `Overall structure of the code is as follows` - the answer is a pineapple - please try to post code that *demonstrates* your issue

Comment: what about passing `that` as a parameter to the `operation` fat arrow function?

Comment: can you provide the wrapper than contains `AnotherClass`?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay, in edited post you can find the link where that class is shown.

Comment: @vikscool, I don't think I can do that as it is a third party library API.

Comment: @Mapper if you the `operation` is to be called internally by the `3rd party library` then I guess your `dummy` objects/variables have to be globally accessible. If so the `this` in that context should refer to the `window` object and hence you can change the code to use `window` instead of `that`.